# How to Import A Upper Level Package in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I have a  file structure like this:

```
/mypkg
    /__init__.py
    /apkg
        /__init__.py
```

How can I import /mypkg/__init__.py from /mypkg/apkg/__init__.py *without using sys.path* and within the package. I mean:

```python
# I do not want to do this since path is already outside the package.
import sys
sys.path.append('../../')
import mypkg
```

Thanks again.

Comment: You can't import *anything* that is not on `sys.path`.  If the module isn't on `sys.path` by normal means (e.g., by being installed to a Python library directory, or by being in the current directory), you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Assume that we had a file /mypkg/afile.py. Then this is what we would do when we were inside /mypkg/apkg/\__init\__.py: `from .. import afile`. I want to learn *how to import a \__init\__ file* just like afile.

Comment: The question I marked as duplicate shows how to do that.  But note that that top-level package (e.g., your `mypkg`) still must be accessible from `sys.path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. You can import from two locations:

1. Your modules located in directories in your Python path (`sys.path`).
2. Your current working directory.

To import from a parent directory, you need to add that directory to your path.

Furthermore, you're creating a circular dependency of sorts. I would strongly suggest your reconsider your overall structure because having a module import its "parent" doesn't really make sense. The fact that you need other files from a higher-level directory suggests that maybe the files in "apkg" should be at the same level as "mypkg".

In reply to your comment: you don't import __init__.py files. They act like a directory for your module so you can utilize the objects and definitions contained in the module. They can also perform initialization on the module contents when its imported, if necessary. There shouldn't be any code in an __init__.py file that you would want to import in another script.